# Bootsrap 5 grid problem, div escaping down

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have the following html codes.

```
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">1</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">2</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">3</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">4</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">5</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">6</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">7</div>
```

Naturally what I want is to see 2 divs side by side on the page. but the result is like this:

[image: wrong result]

Second div in row escaping down. Is there something i missed like margins between divs etc.

I didn't know what to do

Comment: I don't get the same result, see: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/VwBZWQK Did you put a container and row around your columns? See: [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/). When asking a question it is always helpful to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes but when I do this the divs stick together.how can i make a space between them without breaking the grid?

Comment: You have given the columns a background color, and columns touch. Normally you would give columns some content, which can have a background color, and if these contents have a margin they won't touch. Alternatively, if you really want to color the columns themselves you could use some CSS: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/VwBZWQK

Comment: You might consider posting an answer @KIKOSoftware so that future visitors to this Q & A can benefit from your efforts. Those codepen links in comments are nowhere near as visible as the answer field is.

Comment: @HenryEcker: I posted an answer, and added an example of how background coloring of columns is normally done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you haven't surrounded the columns with a container and row, like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <..... your columns here ....>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's these elements that make the Bootstrap columns responsive.

Columns always touch each other, and because you color their background the background colors also touch. With a bit of CSS you can prevent this:

```
.col-styling {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  background-color: green;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

Where this style is applied to each column. See: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/VwBZWQK

It's the [background-clip: content-box;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) that makes this possible. It causes the background not to be painted behind the padding border. A sometimes very useful CSS property.

This is not the normal solution for this when using Bootstrap. Normally you would not give a column a background color, the column is just a box in which you can put content. That content can have a background color, and if you give it a margin then the backgrounds won't touch. Like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="content-styling">1</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="content-styling">2</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="content-styling">3</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="content-styling">4</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="content-styling">5</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="content-styling">6</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="content-styling">7</div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

And then style the content like this:

```
.content-styling {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  background-color: green;
}
```

See: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/RwBbMoR

Answer (score 1):

You must always enclose columns in row class in bootstrap following should work.

```
    <div class="row">       
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">1</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">2</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">3</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">4</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">5</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">6</div>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="col-6 bg-success mt-40 d-inline-block">7</div>
    </div>
```

It's more efficient to use padding.

Remember that margin being outside always adds to the sizing of container so col-6 class now has extra margin left and right thus increasing it's size and overflowing to next line.

Padding is always inset so it doesn't affects the flex sizing being implemented by col class.

try this code below

```
    <div class="row">       
<div class="col-6 p-4 ">
    <div class="bg-success inner-box">1</div>
</div>
<div class="col-6 p-4 ">
    <div class="bg-success inner-box">2</div>
</div>
<div class="col-6 p-4 ">
    <div class="bg-success inner-box">3</div>
</div>
<div class="col-6 p-4 ">
    <div class="bg-success inner-box">4</div>
</div>
<div class="col-6 p-4 ">
    <div class="bg-success inner-box">5</div>
</div>
<div class="col-6 p-4 ">
    <div class="bg-success inner-box">6</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

```
.inner-box{
    height: 100px;
}
```